# How to evaluate and stringify a compile-time constant?

Tags: rust

How to evaluate and stringify a compile-time constant into a `static str`? I suppose there should be a macro for this but couldn't find one. This is the code which shows the intentions and my best effort:

```rust
const NUM: i32 = 11;
fn main() {
    let s = concat!("test", 10, stringify!(NUM), 'b', true);
    assert_eq!(s, "test1011btrue");
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe5b57d614b88a3a0ee17039cb551c49)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`concatcp!`](https://docs.rs/const_format/latest/const_format/macro.concatcp.html) macro from the [`const_format`](https://docs.rs/const_format/latest/const_format/index.html) crate:

```
use const_format::concatcp;

const NUM: i32 = 11;

fn main() {
    let s = concatcp!("test", 10, NUM, 'b', true);
    assert_eq!(s, "test1011btrue");
}
```